# Why does my Apache Nutch warc and commoncrawldump fail after crawl?

Tags: java, nutch, common-crawl, warc

I have successfully crawled a website using Nutch and now I want to create a warc from the results. However, running both the warc and commoncrawldump commands fail. Also, running `bin/nutch dump -segement ....`  works successfully on the same segment folder.

I am using nutch v-1.17 and running:

```
bin/nutch commoncrawldump -outputDir output/ -segment crawl/segments
```

The error from hadoop.log is `ERROR tools.CommonCrawlDataDumper - No segment directories found in my/path/`
despite having just ran a crawl there.

Comment: I have found test segment data which I am able to run commoncrawldump on successfully however I am still unsure on the difference between the two folders of segment data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the segments folder were segments from a previous crawl that were throwing up the error. They did not contain all the segment data as I believe the crawl was cancelled/finished early. This caused the entire process to fail. Deleting all those files and starting anew fixed the issue.